# Android Spinner with different layouts for "drop down state" and "closed state"?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have an Android Spinner view in my layout. I would like that spinner to show only a single text item when closed, but when the user clicks on it (i.e. opens the spinner dialog) I would like to show more extensive information for each item, including an icon and an additional description text view. As it is now the spinner shows the very same layout (icon, title + description) in both states.

If I attach an ArrayAdapter to the spinner, then I get access to something called "setDropDownViewResource" but that's not necessarily what I need, since my spinner data is fetched from a Cursor not from an Array of any kind (I have, as of now, created my own adapter, extending BaseAdapter).

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Please see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880413/text-color-of-a-closed-spinner/34264463#34264463

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880413/text-color-of-a-closed-spinner/34264463#34264463

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You have to create a custom [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) class for the Spinner and overwrite the two methods [`getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) for the normal closed view and [`getDropDownView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html#getDropDownView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) for the drop down list view. Both methods must return a `View` object for a single element.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html) it might help you getting started.

Comment: Took me a while to find it, but exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 17):

I was having problem too. Rather than overriding the class, I hava an easier way to do this.

But first you need to understand the difference between the resource id in the adapter constructor, and the other one in `setDropDownViewResource(...)`. For example,

```
SimpleAdapter adapter =
    new SimpleAdapter(ab.getThemedContext(), data, R.layout.actionbar_dropdown, new String[] { "EventID", "Icon" },
        new int[] { R.id.event_id, R.id.icon });

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.actionbar_list_item);
```

`R.layout.actionbar_dropdown` is the style for ***spinner***, and `R.layout.actionbar_list_item` for every single list item.

I used SimpleAdapter here, since if I use ArrayAdapter, the xml can only be a single TextView.

`R.layout.actionbar_list_item` contains a TextView whose id is `event_id` and an ImageView whose id is `icon`.

`R.layout.actionbar_dropdown` is almost exactly the same as `actionbar_list_item`, but the visibility of ImageView of the latter is set to **GONE**.

In this way every list item has a textview and an imageview, but you will only see a textview on the spinner.

Comment: This really should be the correct answer as it's far easier to implement than the one by Flo (that solution does work as well and may be needed in certain instances, just not strictly required for the OP's question.)

Comment: Excellent  - have a recommend!

Answer (score 12):

Using the code of the tutorial linked by Flo, I created the following CustomSpinnerAdapter in order to show two different sets of strings, one when the items are displayed, and one when not. I hope it helps someone.

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context mContext;
int mTextViewResourceId;
String[] mObjects;
String[] mShortNameObjects;

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                            String[] objects, String[] shortNameObjects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mTextViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    mObjects = objects;
    mShortNameObjects = shortNameObjects;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    TextView row = (TextView) inflater.inflate(mTextViewResourceId, parent, false);
    row.setText(mObjects[position]);

    return row;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    TextView row = (TextView) inflater.inflate(mTextViewResourceId, parent, false);
    row.setText(mShortNameObjects[position]);

    return row;
}
}
```

And the usage **inside a Fragment**:

```
CustomSpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.action_filter), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.action_filter_short_names));
```

Finally, the layout for the spinner item:

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@color/navdraw_list_item_background_default"
    android:padding="5dip" />
```

Comment: You should make use of the `convertView` parameter in your `getView()` and `getDropDownView()` methods.

Answer (score 10):

Only sets the dropdown view resource with your alternative layout:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> genderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.adapter_spinner_white, Constants.GENDER);
genderAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.adapter_spinner_white_dropdown);
view.setAdapter(genderAdapter);
```

For me, it's only a layout with an extra padding left, because my background of spinner is a rounded drawable and require this extra space.

Comment: Works like a charm, cheers! The other solutions are way overcomplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `setUpSpinner()` method after getting reference to spinner

```
// here is setUpSpinner method

private void setupSpinner() {

    // Create adapter for spinner. The list options are from the String array it will use
    // the spinner will use the default layout
    ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.array_dropdown_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify dropdown layout style - simple list view with 1 item per line
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
   // spinner is referenced spinner by finViewById.
    
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.item_a))) {
                    // your code for selected item whose id equals to id to R.string.item_a
                } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.item_b))) {
                    // your code
                } else {
                    // your code
                }
            }
        }

        // Because AdapterView is an abstract class, onNothingSelected must be defined
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // code for nothing selected in dropdown
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an extension of `ArrayAdapter` which preservers as much of its functionality as possible, just sets the long description to the selected item.

First, we need a new model for feeding the adapter. Note that `toString()` returns the `shortDescription` so that the `ArrayAdapter` will show short description in the dropdown:

```
data class DescriptiveArrayItem(val shortDescription: String, val longDescription: String) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return shortDescription
    }
}
```

Second, we create our custom adapter which overrides `getView()` and shows the long description when the item is selected (unfortunately, a lot of fields and methods in `ArrayAdapter` are private so I had to copy them):

```
class DescriptiveArrayAdapter : ArrayAdapter<DescriptiveArrayItem> {
    private var mResource: Int
    private val mFieldId: Int
    private val mContext: Context
    private val mInflater: LayoutInflater

    constructor(context: Context, resource: Int) : super(context, resource) {
        mContext = context
        mFieldId = 0
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        mResource = resource
    }
    constructor(context: Context, resource: Int, textViewResourceId: Int) : super(context, resource, textViewResourceId) {
        mContext = context
        mFieldId = textViewResourceId
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        mResource = resource
    }
    constructor(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: Array<out DescriptiveArrayItem>) : super(context, resource, objects) {
        mContext = context
        mFieldId = 0
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        mResource = resource
    }
    constructor(context: Context, resource: Int, textViewResourceId: Int, objects: Array<out DescriptiveArrayItem>) : super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects) {
        mContext = context
        mFieldId = textViewResourceId
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        mResource = resource
    }
    constructor(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: List<DescriptiveArrayItem>) : super(context, resource, objects) {
        mContext = context
        mFieldId = 0
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        mResource = resource
    }
    constructor(context: Context, resource: Int, textViewResourceId: Int, objects: List<DescriptiveArrayItem>) : super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects) {
        mContext = context
        mFieldId = textViewResourceId
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        mResource = resource
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return createViewFromResource(mInflater, position, convertView, parent, mResource)
    }

    private fun createViewFromResource(inflater: LayoutInflater, position: Int,
                                       convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup, resource: Int): View {
        val text: TextView?
        val view: View = convertView ?: inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false)
        try {
            if (mFieldId == 0) {
                //  If no custom field is assigned, assume the whole resource is a TextView
                text = view as TextView
            } else {
                //  Otherwise, find the TextView field within the layout
                text = view.findViewById(mFieldId)
                if (text == null) {
                    throw RuntimeException("Failed to find view with ID "
                            + mContext.resources.getResourceName(mFieldId)
                            + " in item layout")
                }
            }
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            Log.e("ArrayAdapter", "You must supply a resource ID for a TextView")
            throw IllegalStateException(
                    "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView", e)
        }
        val item: DescriptiveArrayItem? = getItem(position)
        text.text = item?.longDescription
        return view
    }
}
```