# Text color of a closed spinner

Tags: android, spinner, textcolor

I understand that the closed spinner is actually a `View`, I think.  But I am guessing it has a `TextView` there somewhere to show the text.  How do I get access to that `TextView` so I can change the textcolor?

**EDIT:  I need to change this programatically on the fly, not in the XML.**

```
TextView v = (TextView) getView(mySpinner);

v.setTextColor(.....
```

This doesnt work...

Thank you!

```
    array_typ=new String[5];
    array_typ[0]="Pressure";
    array_typ[1]="Level";

    array_typ[2]="Overage";
    array_typ[3]="Under";
    array_typ[4]="Taken";


    adaptertyp = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_typ);
    typ.setAdapter(adaptertyp);
```

Comment: Couldn't you define the color in its XML file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I understand that the closed spinner is actually a View, I think.

Yes. Specifically, it is whatever you told your `SpinnerAdapter` to create.

> But I am guessing it has a TextView there somewhere to show the text.

That would depend on what you told your `SpinnerAdapter` to create.

> How do I get access to that TextView so I can change the textcolor?

Ideally, you don't -- you give it the right color in the first place, via whatever you told your `SpinnerAdapter` to create. If the color varies, override `getView()` in your `SpinnerAdapter` and change the color at that point.

In a pinch, you can try calling `getSelectedView()` to get the current `View` being shown by the closed `Spinner`, but whatever change you make here may be eliminated on the user's next selection, and the alternate color may return later on if the earlier `View` gets recycled.

Comment: I added how I am creating the spinner above.  I am really new to Android and Java so even though your answer sounds like there is an answer I dont know what to enter.  Can you show me a couple line of code that will let me change the text color?  thanks!!!

Comment: @Mark Worsnop: "I added how I am creating the spinner above." -- take a look at your `R.layout.simple_spinner_item` resource and change the color in there.

Comment: @Mark Worsnop: Then you need to override `getView()` and customize the color of your `TextView` as part of that process. At the end of this comment is a link to a free excerpt from one of my books that discusses this process. It does so in the context of `ListView`, but the same concept will hold here. http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

Comment: Thank you I sure do appreciate you help! thanks for taking the time!'

Answer (score 34):

To modify the text color create a new xml file in your res/layout folder (for example my_spinner_text.xml). Add a text view to the new xml file and modify how you want:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/spinnerText" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#CCCCCC" 
    android:textSize="20dp" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

Create an ArrayAdapter that uses the new TextView and set it to your spinner:

```
    Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinner_array,
                R.layout.my_spinner_text);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    localSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: for me, I had to add a namespace in the xml file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView android:id="@+id/spinnerText" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:textColor="#CCCCCC" android:textSize="20dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>

Comment: Your refered website seems to be offline.

Comment: @ala please fix the link in your comment.

Comment: @Diederik if you're referring to http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android. It's not a URI link, but rather just a schema namespace for the XML element, and it is not meant to point to any website. Adding a namespace was suggested by Eclipse to resolve the issue I had. I updated the answer of Vito to include the namespace. However, If you're referring to http://www.designerandroid.com/?p=28, I did not suggest this link, I'm afraid. Maybe Vito can help in this.

Answer (score 23):

You can change the text colour or can access the textview in setOnItemSelectedListener event,

```
            spinnerObject.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                 ((TextView)parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.rgb(249, 249, 249));   

            }
```

Comment: this works ! What Budius suggested didn't because I couldn't set the text color.

Comment: This seems inefficient - setting color every time.  You can set the color on all items in the spinner at once by extending `ArrayAdapter` and overriding `getDropDownView()`.

Answer (score 1):

to do it programatically you have to extend the adapter class, something like:

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdater(this){
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);           
           // change the color here of your v
           v.  ... etc. etc        
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see a `setBackgroundColor()`, but no `setTextColor()`

Answer (score 0):

For Change Textcolor of closed Spinner I have do in this way it works

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = convertView;
  if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.context_row_icon, null);
  }
  TextView mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_label);
  ImageView flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_icon);                

  mTitle.setText(values[position].getLabel(activity));

  if (!((LabelItem) getItem(position)).isEnabled()) {
    mTitle.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.context_item_disabled));
  } else {
    mTitle.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.context_item));
  }
  return view;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = convertView;
  if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.context_row_icon, null);
  }
  TextView mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_label);
  ImageView flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_icon);                

  mTitle.setText(values[position].getLabel(activity));
  mTitle.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.context_item_disabled));
  return view;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Just try this:**

`public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));`