# Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar on Honeycomb

Tags: android

I've an app that would run on both ICS, honeycomb. For both these flavors, I wish to keep same theme: Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar which is SDK >=14.

I created a custom style:

```
    <style name="ActionBar.Dark" parent="@style/ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background_dark</item>
    </style>

<style name="Holo.light.dark.actionbar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Dark</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_transparent_light_holo</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_transparent_dark_holo</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
   </style>
```

But this does only the half job, the dropdown spinner has white background with white text and all window titles are black text on black background.

How do I know of all the attributes that I should set to achieve full Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: @geeknizer, have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880413/text-color-of-a-closed-spinner? Seems that its an internal feature, so you can't change the color of the text's spinner. I found this "workaround" that seems to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361604/how-to-change-the-spinner-font-color

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Sherlock ActionBar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). Under the `library` folder, there is a code intended to make the `ActionBar` work on versions prior to honeycomb. The guy had to set each of the `ActionBar`'s attributes, so it could be handy exploring it. Look at the `abs__styles.xml` under the `values` folder.

Hope it helps and good luck =)

Comment: If you use ActionBarSherlock, you can just use the Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, which will us Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar on 14+, and ActionBarSherlock's custom implementation of the theme on 13-.