# Change textColor of Android Spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text color of a closed spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880413/text-color-of-a-closed-spinner)

I only want to change the textcolor of a spinner.
On Android 2.x it works seamlessly, but Android 4.0 always takes BLACK color. why?

My style:

```
    <style name="spinner">
        <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">20sp</item>
    </style>
```

My spinner:

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/mensaSpinner"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:entries="@array/mensa_list"
   style="@style/spinner"
/>
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880413/text-color-of-a-closed-spinner