# Displaying different text on a spinner item than the selected text, android

Tags: android, text, spinner

I have a spinner item, with three elements, say
i)   A - one
ii)  B - two
iii) C - three.

When the user presses the spinner, the drop down box displays these
elements, but when one of them is selected the only text that should be displayed
is the character, say A (like an index).

I can't seem to find anything useful except using "android:promt" to display a 
legend indicating what each character/code stands for but this looks unprofessional 
and confusing to the user.

Is there anyway I can do this using android?
If anyone can help me, thanks in advance :)

Comment: A similar question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647299/android-spinner-with-different-layouts-for-drop-down-state-and-closed-state/4647702#4647702).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Spinner with different layouts for "drop down state" and "closed state"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647299/android-spinner-with-different-layouts-for-drop-down-state-and-closed-state)