# Android: Set different layouts for Spinner title and dropdown

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, spinner

When my spinner positioned at the actionbar is clicked, it's supposed to present a dropdown with an array of items. Every viewholder for an item has a name and a photo.

However, I want the spinner's title to be another layout (text-only).

In short: How can I set a layout for the title spinner that differs from the dropdown layout?

**Main.java**

```
SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, dummyLists);
    mMyListsSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

**SpinnerAdapter.java**

```
private class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private String[] mListNames;
    SpinnerAdapter(Context context, String[] listNames) {
        this.mListNames = listNames;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(this.mListNames == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return this.mListNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();

        int spinnerItemViewLayout = R.layout.layout_spinner_dropdown_item;

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(spinnerItemViewLayout, parent, false);

        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_spinner_list_name);
        nameTextView.setText(this.mListNames[position]);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**layout_spinner_dropdown_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout_spinner_dropdown_item"
android:layout_width="222dp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_actionbar_height"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_spinner_list_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="LIST"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_subheading"
    android:textColor="@color/color_green_dark"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@color/color_green_dark"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful: [Android Spinner with different layouts for “drop down state” and “closed state”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647299/android-spinner-with-different-layouts-for-drop-down-state-and-closed-state/4647702#4647702)

Basic points:

1. Rewrite `getView()` and `getDropDownView()` in your `Adapter` class [`SpinnerAdapter`]
2. In `getView()`, you should inflate normal layout for title bar, in your case it's a `TextView` only. In `getDropDownView()`, you should inflate your `layout_spinner_dropdown_item.xml`.